# Вывод постов из определенной категории Django

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model

Модели

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name='URL_Категории', unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название')
    descriptions = models.CharField (default='Some descriptions',max_length= 150,verbose_name='Короткое описание')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name='URL_Поста', unique=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Автор')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True,verbose_name='Контент')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Опубликована:')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True, verbose_name='Фото')
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Количество просмотров:')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='tags')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='categories')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        verbose_name = 'Публикация'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Публикации'
```

Вьюха

```
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/category_list.html')
def get_category_post ():
    posts = (
        Post.objects.prefetch_related('categories')
    )
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return (context)
```

Темплейт

```
{% for post in posts %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="section-title">
                {% for category in post.categories.all %}
                <h2 class="title"> {{category.title}} </h2>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="post post-sm">
                {% if post.photo %}
                <a class="post-img" href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{post.photo.url}}" alt="" class="mr-3"></a>
                {% else %}
                <a class="post-img" href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/350/300" alt="lalala"  class="mr-3"></a>
                {%endif%}
                <div class="post-body">
                    <div class="post-category">
                        <a href="category.html">{{post.title}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="post-title title-sm"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{post.descriptions|safe}}</a></h3>
                    <ul class="post-meta">
                        <li><a href="author.html">{{ post.author }}</a></li>
                        <li>{{ post.created_at }}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /post -->
    </div>
<!-- /row -->
{% endfor  %}
```

На выходе получается что выводит категорию и связанный пост, а затем снова ту же категорию и другой связанный пост.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю как сделать так чтобы все связанные посты выводились в одной категории

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы указали `related_name`, а значит можете вот так обратиться к посту:

views.py

```py
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/category_list.html')
def get_category_post():
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
    }
    return (context)
```

index.html

```html
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for post in category.post.all %}
        {{ post.title }}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```